# Pesquisa Dinâmica em c# e WPF

Tags: c#, postgresql, wpf

Bom dia

Gostaria de tirar uma duvida a respeito de uma pesquisa dinâmica.

**Cenário:**

Possuo uma tela de pesquisa, onde o usuário seleciona 3 campos, sendo eles:

1. O primeiro é o campo da tela de pesquisar, onde seleciona qual campo que deseja buscar o valor.
2. O segundo será a condição onde pode selecionar os valores = Contendo, Iniciando, Terminando ou Igual
3. O Terceiro seria o valor que ele deseja pesquisar

Exemplo de tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, como seria a melhor forma de desenvolver isso em C#?

- Criar dropdown com os valores dos campos e condições. Depois criar um
  método onde pego os valores informados e assim gerar um switch case
  com os dados das condições? mais ou menos dessa forma:

->

```
public Cliente pesquisarCliente(string condicao, string campo, string    valor)
           {
            string operador = "";
            string sql;
            switch(condicao)
            {
                case "Condendo":
                    operador = "LIKE %"+ valor +"%";
                    break;
                case "Iniciando":
                    operador = "LIKE %"+ valor;
                    break;
                case "Terminando":
                    operador = "LIKE "+ valor +"%";
                    break;
                case "Igual":
                    operador = " = "+ valor;
                    break;  
            }
            sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTES where @campo "+valor;
            Com = new NpgsqlCommand (sql);
           }
```

Essa seria a melhor maneira ? 
Alguém teria uma outra forma de desenvolver isso?

Não sei se fui claro em minha duvida.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

*OBS:
Estou desenvolvendo em camadas c# com WPF e banco de dados PostgreSQL;
Possuo as camadas
DAL,BLL, GUI e Modelo*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia.

Eu faria a tela apenas com o "valor" e com os "campos" que devem ser utilizados para a pesquisa. Alguma coisa parecida com o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os "campos" selecionados pelo usuário seriam adicionados a uma lista, e o método `pesquisarCliente` ficaria assim:

```
public List<Cliente> pesquisarCliente(string valor, List<string> campos)
{
    string sql;

    string where = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < campos.Count(); i++)
    {
        where += string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", campos[i], valor);
        if (i < campos.Count() - 1)
        {
            where += " OR ";
        }
    }

    sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ({0});", where);

    // Executar sql aqui e retornar lista com clientes encontrados
}
```

Comment: Fuja do like use full text search existem implementações para todos bancos.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Metodo Pesquisar elo artigo
public static List<Cliente> Pesquisar_Artigo(string condicao, string campo, string    valor)
{
    string cn = Properties.Settings.Default.SGV;
    SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(cn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conexao;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    //Faz o teu case aqui
    cmd.CommandText = pesq;

    //Aqui faz o teu parametro
    ex.: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", Nome);
    conexao.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    List<Cliente> Pesquisa = new List<Cliente>();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        //Instacia a classe e depoius adciona todos os atributos ex.: 
        Ciente obj = new Cliente();
        obj.id_cliente = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_cliente"].ToString());
        obj.Nome = dr["Nome"].ToString();

        Pesquisa.Add(obj);
    }
    return Pesquisa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa `Entity Framework + npgsql`
funciona 100% e você faz todo tipo de consulta que precisar

[PostgreSql + EntityFramework](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/783552/using-postgresql-with-entity-framework-in-asp-net)
uma mudança necessária (nao sei se é mais depois de tanto tempo que uso)
é adicionar a `OnModelCreating` em sua classe Context qual é o squema default do banco de dados (acho que isso nao tem no artigo)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
}
```

Exemplo de consulta:

```
public List<Pessoa> ListarPaginado(string noDoc, string nome, string email, int currentPage, int pageSize, out int totalPaginas)
    {
        var pagina = (currentPage - 1) >= 0 ? (currentPage - 1) : 0;
        if (pageSize <= 0) pageSize = 1;

        using (var db = new MeuContext())
        {
            var total = db.Pessoas.Count(x =>
                (
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(noDoc)
                    ? x.Documentos.Any(d => d.NoDoc.Contains(noDoc))
                    : x.Id > 0
                )
                &&
                (
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)
                    ? x.Email.Contains(email)
                    : x.Id > 0
                )
                &&
                (
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome)
                    ? x.Nome.Contains(nome)
                    : x.Id > 0
                )
                && x.Id > 1 //Não mostra o Admin
            );
            totalPaginas = total % pageSize > 0 ? (total / pageSize) + 1 : total / pageSize;

            return db.Pessoas.Where(x =>
                (
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(noDoc)
                    ? x.Documentos.Any(d=>d.NoDoc.Contains(noDoc))  
                    : x.Id > 0
                )
                &&
                (
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)
                    ? x.Email.Contains(email)
                    : x.Id > 0
                )
                &&
                (
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome)
                    ? x.Nome.Contains(nome)
                    : x.Id > 0
                )
                && x.Id > 1 //Não mostra o Admin
            )
            .Include(x=>x.Documentos)
            //.Include(x=>x.Enderecos)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Nome)
            //.ThenBy(x => x.NoDoc)
            .Skip(pagina * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cara, nao consegui entender sua busca, teria como comentar esse código esta estranho pra mim. Obrigado

Comment: simples.
mando a quantidade de registros que eu quero (qtde por página)
a página atual que eu vou mostrar
e os filtros.
usando os filtros eu tenho que saber quantos registros no total eu tenho (para exibir o total de paginas por exemplo), então eu faco um COUNT no meu banco de dados usando os filtros
depois eu uso os mesmo filtros pulando X registros (SKIP(......)) e retornando a quantidade que eu pedi (TAKE(quantidade))

so mandei um exemplo de consulta utilizando Entity Framework (funciona para SqlServer, PostgreSql, Oracle, MySql, só precisa da biblioteca para o banco de dados)

Comment: o resto de como fazer filtros dinamicos fica facil, so manda a classe X preenchida com o que quizer trazer de volta, a consulta já verifica se o campo é válido para filtrar ou nao